# Looping with double quotes in R

Tags: r

I am trying to modify a bunch of excel files in R. I am currently trying to pass the data set names into read_excel as shown below.

```
for(title in c("ABC.xlsx", "DEF.xlsx")){

    library(readxl)
    data_a <- read_excel(paste("Directory/","\"", title,"\"", sep=""))
    data_a1 <- data_a[which(data_a$column_1!='NA'),]
}
```

And I get an error message showing:

```
Error: 'Directory/"ABC.xlsx"' does not exist.
```

So I think I understand I am not using the escape double quotes correctly, but I have tried a bunch of different ways to go about it and I can't figure it out. I really just want to loop some functions through to modify my data and then output some simple stats. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: `read_excel(paste("Directory/", title, sep=""))` should be fine, there is no need to try to escape the quotes as they're not part of the strings.

Comment: Wow awesome thank you. Can't believe how many different combinations of this I tried and it didn't work. Now just need to figure out how to show stats in the console window in the loop.

Comment: I always like to use `title <- list.files("Directory", pattern = ".xlsx")` if I want **all** the files in a directory. Using the `full.names = TRUE` will get rid of the `paste()` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove "\""  in paste, then the file path will be 'Directory/ABC.xlsx' instead of 'Directory/"ABC.xlsx"'.

Answer (score -1):

You need the `library(readxl)` only once and usually at the very top of the code.
Also note that the `data_a1` is going to be overwritten on the 2nd read. All you will get is the "DEF.xlsx" data.

> ```
> library(readxl)
>
> for(title in c("ABC.xlsx", "DEF.xlsx")){
>     data_a <- read_excel(paste("Directory/", title, sep=""))
>     data_a1 <- data_a[which(data_a$column_1!='NA'),]
>     }
> ```

I think what you really want is this

```
Library(readxl)
data_a1 <- data.frame() # make an empty data frame
for(title in c("ABC.xlsx", "DEF.xlsx")) {
data_a <- read_excel(paste("Directory/", title, sep=""))
data_a1 <- rbind(data_a1, data_a) # assuming they have the same number of columns
}
data_a1 <- data_a1[which(data_a1$column_1 != NA),] # or "NA" if that is really present
```